# How do debug header file implemetation (its .cpp) in c++ using GDB

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

I have these 3 file in my program:

1. sample1.h (method in sample1.cpp are defined here)
2. sample1.cpp (all the actual implementations)
3. demo.cpp (I am using the methods in sampe1.cpp here, and have included sample1.h)

Now, I am using **GDB** to debug and I know the basic commands like "break lineno." or "break methodname". But, how do I debug the methods written in sample1.cpp?

***I tried: break "sample1.cpp:mymethod" but it did not work.***

Comment: Your terminology is ambiguous. An implementation and a definition is the same thing; what you generally have in a header file is a *declaration* (unless the implementation is in-lined - in which case it is an inline-definition).  An example would be helpful to remove ambiguity in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
break mymethod
```

As the function name in not ambiguous, it should work.

See. http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/gdbbreak.html#BCPPFUNC

Answer (score 0):

If mymethod is a member of myclass:

```
break myclass::mymethod
```

There should be no need to specify the file.